# Redux store not updating array instead throws an error state. List is not iterable

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Below is the code of my reducer. whenever I am trying to update list array it says it is not iterable. Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am doing?

```
initialState = {
   list: [],
   taskAdded: false,
   taskList: ""
}

export const task = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_TASK:
            return {
                ...state,
                taskList: action.payload,
                taskAdded: true,
                list: [...state.list, action.payload]
            }
        case types.CLEAR_ADD_TASK_STATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                taskList: "",
                taskAdded: false
            }
        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

Comment: I am just assigning default values in the initialState Object

Comment: How does your app use your redux state? I.E. it's possible for UI components to mutate state if careless.

Comment: check the value of state.list whether it's a object

Comment: for using state in the components i am using mapStateToProps and for dispatching i am using mapDispatchToProps. For example if i want to add a task i will dispatch an action using mapDispatchToProps. @DrewReese

Comment: state.list is an array. @pageNotfoUnd

Comment: The reducer for `CLEAR_ADD_TASK_STATE` sets state.list to undefined. I think you forgot to add the old state: `{ ...state,taskList: "",taskAdded: false}`

Comment: i did that just now, but still  i am getting the same error state.list is not interable @HMR

Comment: check `action.payload` data type.It needs to be an array.